# iOS UIKit Multiline label and UITextView give incorrect visual height width

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit, uilabel, uitextview

Im trying to setup a multiline set of views in a UIScrollView and ultimately a UIStackView. I found out I need to dynamically set the scrollviews height to the content to make it work. So when I went to debug why the values never worked I found that the labelType.frame.size is giving me a massive width or like the text was never wrapped, and the height is the height of the devices view.

If I change around the anchors for the content view I can make the text never line break fueling what I see as the CGSize numbers corresponding to the visual size

While the parent view does not even get a size which is why the default UIScrollView won't even work

```
content frame (0.0, 0.0)
uitextType (6791.0, 478.0)
labelType (6781.0, 460.5)
```

In this example I am testing both UITextView and UILabel, I know UITextView is not recommended but testing anyway, it has the same behavior with or without

Worse case I guess I can mix SwiftUI into the Uiview and carry on with work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    
    
    
    let content = UIView()
    content.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(content)


    let constraints2 = [
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        content.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, constant: 0),
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
        //            content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        //            content.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints2)

    
    
    
    let uitextType = UITextView()
    uitextType.backgroundColor = .clear
    uitextType.text = lotatext
    uitextType.isScrollEnabled = false
    uitextType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    content.addSubview(uitextType)
    
    uitextType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.topAnchor).isActive = true
    uitextType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    uitextType.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    uitextType.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.widthAnchor).isActive = true  // -40 2x?! lame
    uitextType.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    uitextType.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
    uitextType.sizeToFit()
    uitextType.contentMode = .topLeft

    
    
    let labelType = UILabel()
    labelType.backgroundColor = .clear
    labelType.text = lotatext
    labelType.numberOfLines = 0
    labelType.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    content.addSubview(labelType)
    
    labelType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.topAnchor).isActive = true
    labelType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    labelType.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    labelType.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    labelType.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    labelType.sizeToFit()
    
    
    
    print("content frame \(content.frame.size)")
    
    print("uitextType \(uitextType.frame.size)")
    
    print("labelType \(labelType.frame.size)")
    
}
```

---

```
    // testing text
let lotatext = """
    Every day is taco ipsum tuesday. It’s a wonderful morning for breakfast tacos. 50 cent tacos! I’ll take 30. CARNE ASADA!! BARBACOA!! I’d have to say, those tacos are on fleek. It’s long been rumored that the chupacabra is really just a crazed man who’s local taco shop went out of business. Does guac cost extra? BARBACOA!! TACOS!! It’s raining tacos, from out of the sky, tacos, don’t even ask why. CARNE ASADA!!

    50 cent tacos! I’ll take 30. I’d have to say, those tacos are on fleek. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. I’ve been following that taco truck around all day. Make it a double there pal. It’s long been rumored that the chupacabra is really just a crazed man who’s local taco shop went out of business. I think I’ve overdosed on tacos. Tacos Al pastor/De Adobada are made of thin pork steaks seasoned with adobo seasoning, then skewered and overlapped on one another on a vertical rotisserie cooked and flame-broiled as it spins.
... snipped extras paragraphs 
"""
```

Comment: To expand on the visual expectedness, the CGSize struct is width height according to the docs. When I punch in the width to the height of the scrollview its clearly not correct, its long but its not a simple swap for height & width

Comment: I don't have an answer for that still but for now this link tutorial worked http://octotap.com/2019/08/03/uistackview-inside-uiscrollview/

Comment: .layoutIfNeeded() looks to give results!! Though don't need this now. Just writing it for reference